# auto_add with FactoryBoy

Tags: django, django-models, factory-boy

This issue: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/102
describes how you should go about testing a 'created' field in django.

How should this be implemented for auto_add (rather than auto_add_now)? I have an "updated" field, but whether I use

```
models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

or override the django model .save() method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """On save, update updated timestamp"""
    self.updated = timezone.now
    return super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can't seem to get FactoryBoy to return the value of updated that I want - it always returns timezone.now()

```
LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.created + timedelta(hours=1))   # ignored by auto_add
```

or using the _create() method as suggested in the GitHub issue:

```
@classmethod
def _create(cls, target_class, *args, **kwargs)
    updated = kwargs.pop('updated', None)
    obj = super(TaskFactory, cls)._create(target_class, *args, **kwargs)
    if updated is not None:
        obj.updated = updated
        obj.save()   # <-- calls .save() method overriding with timezone.now()
    return obj
```

What's the best way to go here?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this, so far, the only way I've found around this is to monkeypatch the .save() method on the original model before passing to Factory boy:

models.py:

```
updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """On save, update updated timestamp"""
    self.updated = timezone.now
    return super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

factories.py:

```
updated = LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.created + timedelta(hours=1))

def patched_save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Task.save = patched_save
```

but would be keen to hear alternate (likely better) suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like this to Task factory:

```
from django.db import models

@classmethod
def _create(cls, target_class, *args, **kwargs):
    updated = kwargs.pop('updated', None)
    task = super()._create(target_class, *args, **kwargs)

    if updated is not None:
        task.updated = updated
        models.Model.save(task)  # This does the magic

    return task
```

Note: we call `models.Model.save(task)`, not `task.save()`

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky solution will be usage in combination with the `freezegun` library.

You need to put a global variable - `freezer` and then freeze the time to desired value on the field declaration.
After this, you execute `_create` as normal. On execute the freezer will be activated and the desired time will be stored in the DB when the model is saved.
After this you need to unfreeze and nullify, to get the true time back on.

The code goes like this:

```
freezer = None

class MyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

....

@factory.lazy_attribute_sequence
    def updated(self, n):
        result_time = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(hours=n)
        global freezer
        freezer = freeze_time(result_time)
        freezer.start()
        return result_time
    
    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super()._create(model_class=model_class, *args, **kwargs)
        global freezer
        freezer.stop()
        freezer = None
        return obj
```

Given example with sequence, but will work with lazy attributes as well.